# MapView fails on a 2.3.3 android device

Tags: android

I have a problem when my application is running on 2.3.3. It seems to crash immediately when trying to load the map. It works on all the emulator versions, and it works on a 2.2 device, but only crashes on the 2.3.3 device. Anyone know why this could happen? The exact log cat dump is

could not find class 'com.google.googlenav.map.TrafficService referenced from method com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap

Comment: which device are you running in?

Comment: show your code. Also specify device names.

Comment: Are you sure that the device with 2.3.3 actually had Google Add-Ons installed?

Comment: Its a spice tablet, and it has google maps on it, so I think the add-ons are installed. I can post the code, but is there any known issue that would cause this where it would work on a 2.2 device (Micromax phone) but not on a 2.3.3 device (spice tablet)?

the devices:  Spice Mi-720, Micromax A52

Answer (score 0):

Go through the url given below...hope it will help...
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think we've done all of that correctly. As I stated, it works on a 2.2 device (Micromax A52), but not on a 2.3.3 device (Spice Mi-720). Any known reasons for this kind of specific issue?